# How can I show again the text next to "Computer" in Finder? Only the icon shows

Tags: macos, mac, finder

Somehow in my Finder's sidebar the "Computer" element under devices doesn't show any description text anymore. It won't kill me, but it's annoying.

Does anyone know how to fix it? I couldn't find the right Google keywords.

[image: My Finder's sidebar]

Comment: What do you see if you either open `terminal` and type `hostname`, or go to System Preferences -> Sharing and look at the Computer Name field?

Answer (score 1):

Try going into System Preferences, then Sharing.  At the top of the window should be a field labeled "Computer Name".  Type in what you want and it should correspond with what you see in Finder's Sidebar.

Comment: Oops, I didn't notice Mikey T.K.'s earlier comment.  If this works, then he gets the credit.